# Creating DB For online ticket booking System

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I have to design an online ticket booking system as a part of my project. I have problems with implementation for advance booking concept. Currently I just use different tables and have a status column to see if it is booked or not and just display them with differnt image src by echoing in `PHP`. I use `MySQL` DB.

Please help me with your ideas to maintain booking for 4 screens(4 shows each) and DB to maintain advance booking after the admin Schedules booking for a corresponding date/dates.

Answer (score 0):

Have you designed an ER diagram for this project? If not, I would start there, it will at least give you a more concrete idea of the relationships between your entities. Furthermore, it will give you an idea about how the internal structures of each table will look and how references will be used, things like foreign keys and such. From there you will have a better understanding of how to structure you PHP queries

Comment: Yes,i did that initially, as i am a newbie and had to complete it quickly had to take this route. yet, jus a logic change couldn hurt me much. Any comments on how to implement the advance booking logic?

Comment: Without any code to show how you started approaching a solution to your problem it will be very hard for me to be able to help you.  If you can give me some code with something partially working I can guide you from there.